# Angular.js View Engine for MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

Im trying to integrate angular into a MVC Razor View Engine application.

But I'm wondering would it be possible to write a new view engine that pretty much sits on top of Razor to allow for a mix of Angularjs and Razor syntax in the same file?

The advantage being that you would not have to install angular, you could just choose this new view engine, and set up routing in global.asax and the view engine would work!

How feasible does this sound? :/  Or is it done already?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Not clear what you are even asking. Angular routing is managed in browser, not server

Comment: You are mixing view engines here that just wont work.  angular is a client side framework that includes a templating engine. Razor is a server side layout rendering engine.  The is no reason why you can't put angular syntax in the Razor view as for the most part Razor will ignore it.  Then send this view down to angular

Comment: I think he means a new server side view engine that mimics how angular view templating works. Might not be a bad idea actually. It would have to be created from scratch of course, but one could get similar angular templating on the server side if they wanted.